# TypeError: json[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

what is the reason of this error?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "homeChart.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function(json) {
                $m = [];
                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    $m.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                    alert(i);    
                }
                dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

the output of homeChart.php is exactly: `[200]`

thanks

Comment: Probably you should do `i < json.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json is [200], which has only one thing in it (200) at index 0.

The for loop uses indices 1 through 10 -- those indices aren't defined for this array.

Comment: but if i do this:     for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) { the error go away, but the result of the alert is : NaN. probably the loop at the moment doesn't make sense, but in the future probably will make

Comment: just delete ["valor" + i]). Solved

Comment: The alert being NaN is a totally different problem -- the original problem with the error is due to the loop and array indices. Without more information I don't have a clue as to why the alert says NaN. The alert should be alerting the loop index, which in this case should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing :
    parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]

Even if `i` is in range, json[0]["valor0"] will be undefined, hens `parseFloat` returning `NaN`.

If your json is an array of floats, you should try something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $m.push(json[i]);
}
```

Hope this will help.